# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/java

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos

```
package conexion;

import com.mysql.jdbc.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;



public class conexion {
    Connection co;  
    Statement stm;

    //jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull [root on Default schema]

    public static Connection iniciarConnection(){   
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
            Connection co= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/java", "root", "");
            Statement stm = co.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Conectado correctamente a la Base de Datos");
            return co;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Clase no encontrada: "+e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error de conexion: "+e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error desconocido: "+e);
        }
            return null;
    }
}
```

Aqui os pongo el OutPut:

> Error de conexion: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/java

Comment: Si alguien tiene este problema que trate instalando la librería de jdbc (o como se llame) en su proyecto. Este video explica como hacerlo:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lX0FhmpHGrc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prueba agregando **":"** después 
de jdbc:mysql, así:

```
Connection co= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java", "root", "");
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias tio, eso era. Yo podria haber estado mil años y no lo averiguaria